# Update table in run time and the column not known in compile time

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to write the SQL to update multiple columns based on some code condition to the table in the code.

For example, make it the easiest one in two columns

`UPDATE table set A = valueA  where conditionA..`

OR  `UPDATE table set B=valueB where conditionA..`

OR `UPDATE table set A=valueA, B=valueB where conditionA..`

The condition is the same, but valueA/valueB may not exist depending on the code

Is there any convenient way to combine them together in one SQL such as the select one `WHERE 1=1 and <condition>` so that I can add the conditions regardless one or more than one conditions?

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question so it uses something other than `A` and `a`, `B` and `b`, and so forth. SQL isn't case sensitive, and your question makes no sense as written. Also, you can format code by selecting it and using the button that looks like `{}` in the editor toolbar, indenting each line 4 spaces, or selecting it all and using Ctrl+K. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Ken White: +1 That's what I call service and friendliness

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same condition you can write the query simply like this:

```
UPDATE [table] SET A = valueA, B=valueB, C=valueC WHERE <condition>
```

But if you need different conditions for all the fields, you could you a CASE operator like this:

```
UPDATE [table] SET A = CASE WHEN <cond_for_A> THEN valA ELSE A END, 
  CASE WHEN <cond_for_B> THEN valB ELSE B END,
  CASE WHEN <cond_for_C> THEN valC ELSE C END
```

Answer (score 0):

You vary the fields being updated, presumably based on some condition in your code, which probably means you won't be able to get away with just one SQL statement - bound parameters cannot "add" or "remove" columns within SQL text.

If you have a small number of columns, you can make a separate SQL statement for each *combination* of them that is of interest. Otherwise, you'll likely need to construct the SQL text dynamically and fill the `SET` clause of your statement so it includes exactly the columns you need.

None of this should serve as an excuse to skip properly binding all parameters, though!